# Where not regexp_like для диапазона

Tags: sql, oracle

### Вводные данные

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id int,
  range2 varchar(55)
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(1, '1 - 9')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(1, '2 - 10')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(1, '133 - 156')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(1, '0 - 0')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(2, '3 - 19')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(2, '0 - 0')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(3, '0 - 0')
    INTO table1(id,range2) VALUES(3, '0 - 0')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Готовая ссылка - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00be78/5

Есть столбец в таблице со строковым типом данных. В нём записи вида "1 - 9", "2 - 10", "133 - 156" (именно с пробелом между числами).

| ID | range2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 - 9 |
| 1 | 2 - 10 |
| 1 | 133 - 156 |
| 1 | 0 - 0 |
| 2 | 3 - 19 |
| 2 | 0 - 0 |
| 3 | 0 - 0 |
| 3 | 0 - 0 |

### Ожидаемый результат

Необходимо, чтобы в результате запроса остались только те ID, у которых **все** значения в столбце Range соответствовали 0 - 0 (т.е. ID1 и ID2 не подходят, т.к. содержат не только 0 - 0)

| ID | range2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 - 0 |
| 3 | 0 - 0 |

### Как пытался решить

С помощью конструкции where not regexp_like. Но шаблон вида

***^[1-9]+(.)+[1-9]$+***

Не работает.

```
select id, range2 from table
where NOT regexp_like (range,^[1-9]+(.)+[1-9]$+)
```

При запросе "в лоб" Where range2 = '0 - 0' туда попадают ID1 и ID2

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00be78/5

С регулярками очень не очень. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, отредактировал

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    AND t2.range2 <> '0 - 0'
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i6Rw_-f0)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! За терпение и помощь!